# KhanAcademy API

Tags: coldfusion, khan-academy

I want to ask my students to add me as their coach at khanacademy.org.

Q: What kind of data can I get from Khan Academy's API?  Can I get the videos that they've watched, or their badges?

Comment: BTW, I would consider posting some initial work or research you have done already to answer this question. @MattBusche was right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took me 3 seconds of googling to find this

From their documentation -

Videos they've watched https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API-Methods#wiki-user-videos

Badges they've earned - https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API-Methods#wiki-badges

Answer (score 3):

From :[Kahn API Explorer](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API)

> Authenticated api calls will give you information about the logged in user (either a student or a coach/parent), such as videos seen, exercises completed, playlist progress and so forth. This repository's README includes helpful instructions (and a python script) for authenticated api calls. Try it out!